# HP laptop slows down when charge is connected

Tags: laptop, power, charger, hp, cpu-throttling

My hp-laptop throttles drastically when i connect the charger to it. There is no load on the laptop but i think load does not matter as it works just fine when charger is removed.

It is HP-15-dy1xxx with NVMe, 16GB RAM (Only 5GB in use) installed with Ubuntu 22.04, temperatures are under control.

I dont think it is a software (driver) issue because it takes so long to complete the boot up process if charger is connected and it runs very slow in the BIOS settings too.

I ran a script to show the performance difference when charger is connected and here are the results:

> It runs an infinite for-loop and measures time taken to run 100,000 iterations.

> Initially the charger was connected when i started the script.

```
04:19:23 PM IST,      Time Taken: 4822 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 1
04:19:28 PM IST,      Time Taken: 5023 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 2
04:19:33 PM IST,      Time Taken: 4847 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 3 
04:19:38 PM IST,      Time Taken: 4880 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 4 
04:19:42 PM IST,      Time Taken: 4002 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 5 #Charger Disconnected. You can see the performance is recovering.
04:19:44 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1923 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 6
04:19:46 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1955 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 7
04:19:48 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1976 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 8
04:19:50 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1934 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 9
04:19:51 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1925 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 10
04:19:53 PM IST,      Time Taken: 2005 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 11
04:19:55 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1930 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 12
04:19:57 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1988 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 13
04:19:59 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1918 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 14
04:20:01 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1929 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 15
04:20:03 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1721 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 16
04:20:04 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1174 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 17
04:20:05 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1145 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 18
04:20:07 PM IST,      Time Taken: 1229 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 19
04:20:08 PM IST,      Time Taken: 932 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 20
04:20:08 PM IST,      Time Taken: 859 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 21
04:20:09 PM IST,      Time Taken: 851 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 22
04:20:10 PM IST,      Time Taken: 841 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 23
04:20:11 PM IST,      Time Taken: 844 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 24
04:20:12 PM IST,      Time Taken: 746 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 25
04:20:12 PM IST,      Time Taken: 317 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 26  #After approx 40 seconds now it is performing fine. Look at the end how it throttles when i will reconnect the charger.
04:20:12 PM IST,      Time Taken: 320 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 27
04:20:13 PM IST,      Time Taken: 335 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 28
04:20:13 PM IST,      Time Taken: 327 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 29
04:20:13 PM IST,      Time Taken: 336 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 30
04:20:14 PM IST,      Time Taken: 329 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 31
04:20:14 PM IST,      Time Taken: 328 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 32
04:20:14 PM IST,      Time Taken: 327 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 33
04:20:15 PM IST,      Time Taken: 325 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 34
04:20:15 PM IST,      Time Taken: 320 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 35
04:20:15 PM IST,      Time Taken: 327 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 36
04:20:16 PM IST,      Time Taken: 336 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 37
04:20:16 PM IST,      Time Taken: 318 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 38
04:20:16 PM IST,      Time Taken: 330 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 39
04:20:17 PM IST,      Time Taken: 330 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 40
04:20:17 PM IST,      Time Taken: 329 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 41
04:20:17 PM IST,      Time Taken: 327 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 42
04:20:18 PM IST,      Time Taken: 331 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 43
04:20:18 PM IST,      Time Taken: 323 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 44
04:20:18 PM IST,      Time Taken: 325 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 45
04:20:19 PM IST,      Time Taken: 326 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 46
04:20:19 PM IST,      Time Taken: 313 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 47
04:20:19 PM IST,      Time Taken: 321 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 48
04:20:20 PM IST,      Time Taken: 346 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 49
04:20:20 PM IST,      Time Taken: 314 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 50
04:20:20 PM IST,      Time Taken: 375 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 51
04:20:21 PM IST,      Time Taken: 333 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 52
04:20:21 PM IST,      Time Taken: 346 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 53
04:20:21 PM IST,      Time Taken: 316 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 54
04:20:22 PM IST,      Time Taken: 323 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 55
04:20:22 PM IST,      Time Taken: 312 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 56
04:20:22 PM IST,      Time Taken: 324 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 57
04:20:23 PM IST,      Time Taken: 330 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 58
04:20:23 PM IST,      Time Taken: 321 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 59
04:20:23 PM IST,      Time Taken: 326 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 60
04:20:24 PM IST,      Time Taken: 329 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 61
04:20:24 PM IST,      Time Taken: 323 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 62
04:20:24 PM IST,      Time Taken: 333 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 63
04:20:25 PM IST,      Time Taken: 333 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 64
04:20:25 PM IST,      Time Taken: 325 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 65
04:20:25 PM IST,      Time Taken: 331 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 66
04:20:26 PM IST,      Time Taken: 331 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 67
04:20:26 PM IST,      Time Taken: 329 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 68
04:20:26 PM IST,      Time Taken: 328 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 69
04:20:27 PM IST,      Time Taken: 330 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 70
04:20:27 PM IST,      Time Taken: 317 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 71
04:20:27 PM IST,      Time Taken: 327 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 72
04:20:28 PM IST,      Time Taken: 323 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 73
04:20:28 PM IST,      Time Taken: 321 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 74
04:20:28 PM IST,      Time Taken: 325 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 75
04:20:29 PM IST,      Time Taken: 325 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 76
04:20:29 PM IST,      Time Taken: 319 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 77
04:20:29 PM IST,      Time Taken: 316 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 78
04:20:33 PM IST,      Time Taken: 3419 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 79 #I again plugged in the charger.
04:20:38 PM IST,      Time Taken: 4856 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 80
04:20:42 PM IST,      Time Taken: 4813 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 81
04:20:47 PM IST,      Time Taken: 4875 Milliseconds,            Iteration: 82
```

It takes about 30-45 seconds to resume the normal performance when charger is disconnected. But throttles immediately when it is re-connected. I tried with different chargers but same results.

Any hint or help?

Comment: Does performance come back once the battery is fully charged or is it bad all of the time? It could be that the battery charging circuitry is overheating and your firmware is detecting that and throttling the CPU. You can use the Sensors tool in HWinfo to check all the motherboard temperature sensors.

Comment: Do you have a power profile set, with On Battery set to Performance, and On Power set to Balanced/Low Performance?

Comment: @Mokubai No, it behaves same regardless the battery is full or not. I dont think it is overheating. I slows immediately when charger is connected. I checked temperature: acpitz=46.0°C 
SEN1=39.0°C 
INT3400 Thermal=20.0°C 
B0D4=46.0°C 
x86_pkg_temp=45.0°C    
```
@spikey_richie I tried to switch the profiles but it is the same.

Comment: This is why I am quite sure there is a hardware issue needing service.

Comment: (1) Have you tried another power cable and is yours the original one? (2) Try removing the battery and running directly from the AC power supply, if possible. (3) This might be a problem with the power supply.

Comment: I think that the problem existed with a different charger (see post) so most likely a hardware issue with the laptop,

Answer (score 0):

> it runs very slow in the BIOS settings too.

That means the issue is not a software issue.

Attaching the charger could be disconnecting the battery - hardware issue. The machine needs the battery with the charger to run at proper speed.

It is possible the battery circuit (or battery itself) has a hardware issue as well.

You need to take the machine to a local service shop and have it repaired.

Answer (score 0):

It was a hardware issue. After replacing the charging port of the laptop it is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My Dell laptop had nearly the exact same issue. Some differences- if the power adapter was plugged in when I booted up, I got a BIOS warning, saying the voltage on the power adapter is incorrect.  The cause was also very similar.  The physical connector on the off brand adapter wasn't quite long enough to make the appropriate connections inside.  I replaced the power adapter and it worked fine afterwards.